# Matplotlib : What is the function of cmap in imshow?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, imshow, colormap

I'm trying to learn opencv using python and came across this code below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

BLUE = [255,0,0]

img1 = cv2.imread('opencv_logo.png')
replicate = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img1,10,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
reflect = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img1,10,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_REFLECT)
reflect101 = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img1,10,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_REFLECT_101)
wrap = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img1,10,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_WRAP)
constant= cv2.copyMakeBorder(img1,10,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=BLUE)

plt.subplot(231),plt.imshow(img1,'gray'),plt.title('ORIGINAL')
plt.subplot(232),plt.imshow(replicate,'gray'),plt.title('REPLICATE')
plt.subplot(233),plt.imshow(reflect,'gray'),plt.title('REFLECT')

plt.subplot(234),plt.imshow(reflect101,'gray'),plt.title('REFLECT_101')
plt.subplot(235),plt.imshow(wrap,'gray'),plt.title('WRAP')
plt.subplot(236),plt.imshow(constant,'gray'),plt.title('CONSTANT')

plt.show()
```

source : http://docs.opencv.org/master/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html#exercises

What does plt.imshow(img1, 'gray') do? I tried searching Google and all I could understand was that the 'gray' argument was a Color map. But my image (pic is there on the site. see link) is not displayed in grayscale. I tried removing the second argument. So the code was like plt.imshow(img1). It executes. The image remains same as before. Then what does the second argument 'gray' do? Can someone explain all this to me? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

PS. I'm totally new to Matplotlib

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When `img1` has shape `(M,N,3)` or `(M,N,4)`, the values in `img1` are interpreted as RGB or RGBA values. In this case the cmap is ignored. Per [the `help(plt.imshow)` docstring](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow):

> cmap : `~matplotlib.colors.Colormap`, optional, default: None
>
> If None, default to rc `image.cmap` value. **`cmap` is ignored when
>   `X` has RGB(A) information**

However, if `img` were an array of shape `(M,N)`, then the cmap controls the colormap used to display the values.

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 as axes_grid1
np.random.seed(1)

data = np.random.randn(10, 10)

fig = plt.figure()
grid = axes_grid1.AxesGrid(
    fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(1, 2), axes_pad = 0.5, cbar_location = "right",
    cbar_mode="each", cbar_size="15%", cbar_pad="5%",)

im0 = grid[0].imshow(data, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
grid.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(im0)

im1 = grid[1].imshow(data, cmap='jet', interpolation='nearest')
grid.cbar_axes[1].colorbar(im1)
plt.savefig('/tmp/test.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0, dpi=200,)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain what cmap is used for? Why do we use color maps?

Comment: The colormap is a dictionary which maps numbers to colors. Matplotlib provides many [built-in colormaps](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps). When you have a 2D array, such as `data` above, the values at each grid point is a float between 0 and 1. The `gray` colormap maps 0 to black and 1 to white. The `jet` colormap maps 0 to blue and 1 to red. See the link for a visual display of the colors in between.

Comment: Correction: The `data` array used above has values which are normally distributed; by default the colormap adjusts the colors to the data's range.

Comment: @ubuntu: I understood your first comment, then got confused after the last one, what exactly does it mean? a previously color image, was represented in floats (2d, 1 channel), and now, we want to get that back to rgb  ?

Comment: @Hossein: Since `data = np.random.randn(10, 10)`, the minimum and maximum values of `data` could be different from 0 and 1. The `imshow` function normalizes `data` so that `min(data)` gets mapped to 0 and `max(data)` gets mapped to 1. Then the colormap is applied. The purpose of the [second comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625952/matplotlib-what-is-the-function-of-cmap-in-imshow/25626042?noredirect=1#comment40039776_25626042) was merely to stress the existence of that normalization step.

Comment: Thanks.I have seen people using cmap=gray, on color images, and it works, but I cant do it ([here](https://render.githubusercontent.com/view/ipynb?commit=22fc6dd82cbbb929965f3ce5248eaac422cd8560&enc_url=68747470733a2f2f7261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f706b6d6974616c2f4341444c2f323266633664643832636262623932393936356633636535323438656161633432326364383536302f73657373696f6e2d302f73657373696f6e2d302e6970796e62&nwo=pkmital%2FCADL&path=session-0%2Fsession-0.ipynb&repository_id=62756493#resizing-images)
why is that?

Comment: The [imshow function](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow) can accept a data array of shape `(n,m)`, `(n,m,3)` or `(n,m,4)`. When you specify a colormap, the data array must be of shape `(n,m)`. Per the docs, "cmap is ignored when X has RGB(A) information".